# How do i join a table to itself using an incremental loop using a variable that is set in a table row?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, self-join

How do i join a table to itself using an incremental loop using a variable that is set in a table row?

The closest I can get is below and but:

```
SELECT  A.post_id, A.meta_value AS From_Date, B.meta_value AS To_Date
FROM wpmega_postmeta A, wpmega_postmeta B
WHERE A.post_id = B.post_id 
    AND (A.meta_key = 'unavailable_dates_0_dates_from_date'
    AND B.meta_key = 'unavailable_dates_0_dates_to_date')
    OR (A.meta_key = 'unavailable_dates_1_dates_from_date'
    AND B.meta_key = 'unavailable_dates_1_dates_to_date')
```

Unfortunately I can't find out how I can use the unavailable_dates row as a variable to join the subsequent date fields.

This is the data in the table

```
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------+
| meta_id | post_id |              meta_key               | meta_value |
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------+
|      12 |     161 | unavailable_dates                   |          3 |
|      16 |     161 | unavailable_dates_0_dates_from_date |   20200610 |
|      18 |     161 | unavailable_dates_0_dates_to_date   |   20200630 |
|      30 |     161 | unavailable_dates_1_dates_from_date |   20200701 |
|      32 |     161 | unavailable_dates_1_dates_to_date   |   20200709 |
|      62 |     260 | unavailable_dates                   |          1 |
|      56 |     260 | unavailable_dates_0_dates_from_date |   20200801 |
|      58 |     260 | unavailable_dates_0_dates_to_date   |   20200830 |
|      96 |     161 | unavailable_dates_2_dates_from_date |   20210610 |
|      98 |     161 | unavailable_dates_2_dates_to_date   |   20210630 |
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

This is the result I want

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| post_id | from_date | to_date  |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|     161 |  20200610 | 20200630 |
|     161 |  20200701 | 20200709 |
|     260 |  20200801 | 20200830 |
|     161 |  20210610 | 20210630 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like string functions and aggregation can give you the result that you want:

```
select 
    post_id,
    max(case when meta_key like '%_from_date' then meta_value end) from_date,
    max(case when meta_key like '%_to_date'   then meta_value end) to_date
from wpmega_postmeta 
where meta_key like 'unavailable_dates_%'
group by post_id, left(meta_key , 19)
order by post_id, from_date
```

The query filters on `meta_key`s that start with `'unavailable_dates_'`, and then group the results by `post_id` and the first 19 characters of the meta key (this includes the number that is part of the string, like `'unavailable_dates_0'`). Then all that is left to do is put the `from_date` and `end_date` in two separate columns.

You may want to adjust the length of the string part that is used for grouping if there may be more than one digit (without seeing more data, I can't suggest). Also, you may want to make the `where` predicate more specific, if other `meta_key`s have similar descriptions - possibly using a regex, like:

```
where meta_key regexp '^unavailable_dates_[0-9]+_dates_(from_date)|(to_date)$'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b71095d796e536ffd2b6e749bf440512)**:

```
post_id | from_date |  to_date
------: | --------: | -------:
    161 |  20200610 | 20200630
    161 |  20200701 | 20200709
    260 |  20200801 | 20200830
```

Comment: I wonder what the data looks like when/if unavailable_dates has a meta_value > 2

Comment: Wow that uses a lot more features of mysql than i new about. What is the 19 about in group by post_id, left(meta_key , 19)?

Comment: @Tristanisginger: see the latest edit of my answer, that gives more details.

Comment: @P.Salmon: yes, I was speculating on that, and later added more thoughts to my answer.